# What is difference between dispatch and bindActionCreators?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

> If we are connecting to the action by using the dispatch there are two way:-

```
1. this.props.dispatch(requestEmployees());

2. const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      requestEmployees: () => dispatch(requestEmployees())

    });
```

> If we are doing the same with the help of bindActionCreators then our
>   code we will be:-

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators({ editLabResult: requestEmployees}, dispatch);
    }
```

> Now my question is, which one I should use **dispatch or**
>   **bindActionCreators**? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's actually the same thing. The result of

```
bindActionCreators({ editLabResult: requestEmployees}, dispatch);
```

Is what you've manually created:

```
requestEmployees: () => dispatch(requestEmployees())
```

---

According to the redux [`bindActionCreators`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html#bindactioncreatorsactioncreators-dispatch) documentation:

> Turns an object whose values are action creators, into an object with
>   the same keys, but with every action creator wrapped into a **dispatch**
>   call so they may be invoked directly.

```
bindActionCreators({ editLabResult: requestEmployees, anotherAction, etc... }, dispatch);
```

Instead of using `bindActionCreators`, you can pass the object to the [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method, and it will do the wrapping for you:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { editLabResult: requestEmployees, anotherAction, etc... })
```