# How to use multiple multiActions in react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am importing multiple multiactions into my component and using connect. I have import one multaction and it works just fine, but I can't figure out how to do multiple. Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../../actions/posts_actions';
import * as actionsIndex from '../../actions/index';
import * as actionsComments from '../../comments_actions';

function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) {
  return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ShowPosts);
```

Comment: `redux` provide an utility function called `bindActionCreators`. Take a look to the official documentation http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html and also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41342635/273355. Ideally you could do something like `bindActionCreators({...actions, ...actionsIndex, ...actionsComments}, dispatch)`

Comment: Why do we use the spread operator instead of just putting actions, actionsIndex, actionsComments? It did work I was just wondering.

Comment: Two different ways to achieve the same thing :) Creating a new object from three objects. Although the one provided by myself needs a transpiler, the one provided by @D-reaper can substituted by a polyfill

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass create a mapDispatchToProps that uses bindActionCreators and pass that as a second argument to `connect` instead of actions.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, actions, actionsIndex, 
    actionsComments), dispatch)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowPosts);
```

Comment: Thank you! I also tried the other way in the comment and it worked, why did we not have to do ...actions, ...actionsIndex, ...actionsComments as @Ematipico used?

Comment: You can use that too if you want and it will still work. The spread operator is just a syntactic sugar.